# Dictionary by XML file

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

We have a XML dictionary file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<words>
    <word>
        <phrase lang="IR">حسابدار</phrase>
        <phrase lang="FR">Comptable</phrase>
        <phrase lang="CN">会计</phrase>
        <phrase lang="US">Accountant</phrase>
    </word>
    <word>
        <phrase lang="IR">حسابرس</phrase>
        <phrase lang="FR">Auditeur</phrase>
        <phrase lang="CN">核数师</phrase>
        <phrase lang="US">Auditor</phrase>
    </word>
    <word>
        <phrase lang="IR">مهندس</phrase>
        <phrase lang="FR">Ingénieur</phrase>
        <phrase lang="CN">工程师</phrase>
        <phrase lang="US">Engineer</phrase>
    </word>
</words>
```

We need a PHP code that find the text containing "ginee" (Engineer) and return that French translate (Ingénieur).

Our PHP code is

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//word/phrase[contains(..,"ngin")]');
var_dump($nodes);
?>
```

and it return

```
array(4) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "IR" } [0]=> string(10) "مهندس" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "FR" } [0]=> string(10) "Ingénieur" } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "CN" } [0]=> string(9) "工程师" } [3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(2) "US" } [0]=> string(8) "Engineer" } }
```

Comment: *"We need a PHP code"* ... well it's up to you to write that code, this isn't a code writing service. Please show what you have tried that isn't working and then you should get plenty of help. Otherwise, if you have nothing so far it's time to do some research on your part and come back when you do have some code

Comment: Thank you for your TRY ! your warning lines is more than our needed codes !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already got the nodes you want from the query you used, just access the property (the french `FR`) using `->attributes()`:

Basic idea:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//word/phrase[contains(..,"ngin")]');
$lang_needed = 'FR';
$result = '';
if(!empty($nodes)) {
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        if((string) $node->attributes()->lang === $lang_needed) {
            // $result = (string) $node;
            echo $node;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also devise your query this way:

```
$lang_needed = 'FR';
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//word/phrase[contains(..,'A')][@lang = '{$lang_needed}']");
if(!empty($nodes as $node)) {
    // $result = (string) $node;
    echo $node;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a class that parses XML into a structure

```
 class Simple_Parser
{
    var $parser;
    var $error_code;
    var $error_string;
    var $current_line;
    var $current_column;
    var $data = array();
    var $datas = array();

    function parse($data)
    {

        $this->parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
         //UTF-8 encoding geoffers_
        xml_set_object($this->parser, $this);
        xml_parser_set_option($this->parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
        xml_set_element_handler($this->parser, 'tag_open', 'tag_close');
        xml_set_character_data_handler($this->parser, 'cdata');
        if (!xml_parse($this->parser, $data))
        {
            $this->data = array();
            $this->error_code = xml_get_error_code($this->parser);
            $this->error_string = xml_error_string($this->error_code);
            $this->current_line = xml_get_current_line_number($this->parser);
            $this->current_column = xml_get_current_column_number($this->parser);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data = $this->data['child'];
        }
        xml_parser_free($this->parser);
    }

    function tag_open($parser, $tag, $attribs)
    {
        $this->data['child'][$tag][] = array('data' => '', 'attribs' => $attribs, 'child' => array());
        $this->datas[] =& $this->data;
        $this->data =& $this->data['child'][$tag][count($this->data['child'][$tag])-1];
    }

    function cdata($parser, $cdata)
    {
        $this->data['data'] .= $cdata;
    }

    function tag_close($parser, $tag)
    {
        $this->data =& $this->datas[count($this->datas)-1];
        array_pop($this->datas);
    }
}
```